# Global name in self/class?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am having issues calling variables in my class. I have everything set up as self's and what have but i am still getting errors. I think i am having a hard time figuring this out cause i am new to 3.0 scripting.

Here is my script:

http://pastebin.com/9Lrw399E

here is the error:

```
command = 'tcpdump -c5 -tttt -w {0} host {1}'.format(raw, input_host)
NameError: global name 'raw' is not defined
```

if i make them self.raw or self.input_host

it get this:

```
command = 'tcpdump -c5 -tttt -w {0} host {1}'.format(self.raw, self.input_host)
AttributeError: 'MainLoop' object has no attribute 'raw'
```

Comment: Could you avoid using external sites for code and include all relevant parts in the question?

Comment: It would be nice if you could update your question and reconcile why the answer you accepted has the very code in it that you say also doesn't work at the end of you question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
command = 'tcpdump -c5 -tttt -w {0} host {1}'.format(raw, input_host)
```

Should be:

```
command = 'tcpdump -c5 -tttt -w {0} host {1}'.format(self.raw, self.input_host)
```

Notice the `self`.

Comment: which i do and i get this error:

    command = 'tcpdump -c5 -tttt -w {0} host {1}'.format(self.raw, self.input_host)

AttributeError: 'MainLoop' object has no attribute 'raw'

Comment: +1 for fastest on the trigger *and* catching the `input_host` as well

Comment: @Pastelinux this is because you only ever assign it a value in `inputname`. When you don't enter a filename, your format command is the first time you refer to the variable.

Comment: @Pastelinux: Line 5, it should `self.time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d(%H:%M)")`

Comment: You also need to prepend `self` in line 37 to `raw`, `input_host` and `input_host2`.

Comment: Alright thank you sukhbir, DiPaolo, unholy, and limberg. Heres the fixed code for future viewers: http://pastebin.com/mU6M0YtV

Answer (score 1):

try

```
command = 'tcpdump -c5 -tttt -w {0} host {1}'.format(self.raw, self.input_host)
```

Unless you're passing raw and input_host in as function parameters, you need to use self.variable to look up the variable for the class instance.

Edit:  You'll also need to make sure that whatever functions define self.raw and self.input_host are called before this line of code is run.  From your code, if you call `MainLoop.cmd()`, you must call `MainLoop.host()` AND `MainLoop.inputname()` *before* `cmd()` so that `self.raw` and `self.input_host` exist in the instance of the class.

In this case, you should probably create a constructor for your class that at least creates the instance variables

```
class MainLoop:
    def __init__(self):
        self.raw = None
        self.input_host = None
```

and then check the value of self.raw and self.input_host before creating the command.

```
def cmd(self):
    if self.raw is not None and self.input_host is not None:
        command = 'tcpdump -c5 -tttt -w {0} host {1}'.format(self.raw, self.input_host)
        subprocess.call(command.split(), shell=False)
```

Comment: alright i see what you saying. Let me see if i can figure it out. I'll report back when i do.